# PHPExcel not working perfectly

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I use `PHPExcel` library from [here](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) to create an excel file extension `.xlsx` 
for that i use `php` and `mysql` the data of this excel file is from `mysql` database.

After i create the code i receive this message:

> Excel can't open the file because the file format or file extension is
>   not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the
>   file extension matches the format of the file

To solve this problem i use:

```
ob_start(); ob_end_clean();
```

After that i download the file and try to open the excel file i have this message:

> We found a problem with some content in your file.Do you want to us to
>   try to recover as much as we can?if you trust the source of this
>   workbook,click yes.

When i click yes i have this message:

> Excel completed file level validation and repair. Some parts of this
>   workbook may have been repaired or discarded.

I click close the excel file open but inside this excel file i have some empty rows with my data.

This is my code to download an excel file using `PHPExcel`

```
ob_start();
include("includes/connect.php");
require_once'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
//Create PHPExcel object
$excel=new PHPExcel();
//selecting active sheet
$excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$row=21;
while($data=mysqli_fetch_object($query)){
$excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellvalue('A'.$row,$data->db_maid)
    ->setCellvalue('B'.$row,$data->db_date) 
    ->setCellvalue('C'.$row,$data->db_client)
    ->setCellvalue('D'.$row,$data->db_esid)
    ->setCellvalue('E'.$row,$data->db_type)    
    ->setCellvalue('F'.$row,$data->db_phone)
    ->setCellvalue('G'.$row,$data->db_mobile) 
    ->setCellvalue('H'.$row,$data->db_contactperson)
    ->setCellvalue('I'.$row,$data->db_competetivecompany)
    ->setCellvalue('J'.$row,$data->db_category)    
    ->setCellvalue('K'.$row,$data->db_process)
    ->setCellvalue('L'.$row,$data->db_status) 
    ->setCellvalue('M'.$row,$data->db_rate) 
    ->setCellvalue('N'.$row,$data->db_doc)
    ->setCellvalue('O'.$row,$data->nextDate)
    ->setCellvalue('P'.$row,$data->db_ndstatus)
    ->setCellvalue('Q'.$row,$data->db_pnote) 
    ->setCellvalue('R'.$row,$data->meetingStatus) 
    ->setCellvalue('S'.$row,$data->db_ncam)    
    ->setCellvalue('T'.$row,$data->medit)
    ->setCellvalue('U'.$row,$data->name);
    //incriment the row
$row++;    
}
//set column width
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(10);
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(20);
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(20);
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(20);
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('E')->setWidth(20);
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('F')->setWidth(20);
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('G')->setWidth(20);
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('H')->setWidth(20);
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('I')->setWidth(20);
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('J')->setWidth(20);
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('K')->setWidth(20);
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('L')->setWidth(20);
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('M')->setWidth(20);
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('N')->setWidth(20);
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('O')->setWidth(20);
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('P')->setWidth(20);
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('Q')->setWidth(20);
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('R')->setWidth(20);
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('S')->setWidth(20);
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('T')->setWidth(20);
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('U')->setWidth(20);
//make table headers
$excel->getActiveSheet()
      ->setCellValue('A1','List Of Marketing')
      ->setCellValue('A3','#')
      ->setCellValue('B3','Date')
      ->setCellValue('C3','Client')
      ->setCellValue('D3','ES')
      ->setCellValue('E3','Type')
      ->setCellValue('F3','Phone')
      ->setCellValue('G3','Mobile')
      ->setCellValue('H3','Contact Person')
      ->setCellValue('I3','Competetive Company')
      ->setCellValue('J3','Categoty')
      ->setCellValue('K3','Process')
      ->setCellValue('L3','Status')
      ->setCellValue('M3','Rate')
      ->setCellValue('N3','Date Of Calling')
      ->setCellValue('O3','Next Date')
      ->setCellValue('P3','Next Date Status')
      ->setCellValue('K3','Phone Note')
      ->setCellValue('R3','Meeting Status')
      ->setCellValue('S3','Next Call After Meeting')
      ->setCellValue('T3','Edit Date')
      ->setCellValue('U3','Staff');
//Margin The title
$excel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A1:U1');
//aligning
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
//styling
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->applyFromArray(
array(
      'font'=>array(
          'size'=>24,
      )
)
);
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A3:U3')->applyFromArray(
array(
   'font'=>array(
       'bold'=>true
   ),
    'borders'=>array(
        'allborders'=>array(
            'style'=>PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN
        )
    )
)
);
//give border to data
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A4:U'.($row-1))->applyFromArray(
array(
    'borders'=>array(
        'outline'=>array(
            'style'=>PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN
        ),
        'vertical'=>array(
            'style'=>PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN
        )
    )
)
);
//write the result to a file
$file=PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel,'Excel2007');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="marketing.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control:max-age=0');
ob_end_clean();

//output to php output instead of filename
$file->save('php://output');
```

My question is How to solve this problem i don't want this message appear also i don't want to have an empty rows in my excel also `ob_end_clean()` is a real solution for the first message because i saw a tutorial on the internet and his code work correctly without using the `ob_end_clean()` or the `ob_start()`?

Comment: Using `ob_start()` and `ob_end_clean()` that way means any errors PHP is outputting are discarded. What happens if you remove those two calls and save the document to an actual file? Do you see any errors? Then what happens if you download and open the file that was saved?

Comment: @rickdenhaan if i remove this two calls i can't open the file and i receive the first message put it above and what you mean by save the document to an actual file?

Comment: I mean instead of `$file->save('php://output');` to save to an actual file, e.g. `$file->save('/tmp/marketing.xlsx');` and removing the `header()` calls (temporarily, just for testing)

Comment: @rickdenhaan ok i will test it

Comment: When i use what you suggest i have this errors Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Writer_Exception' with message 'Could not close zip file /tmp/marketing.xlsx.' in C:\wamp\www\eiwms\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007.php on line 389    PHPExcel_Writer_Exception: Could not close zip file /tmp/marketing.xlsx. in C:\wamp\www\eiwms\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007.php on line 389

Comment: Also, you can open the file using a text editor, you'll be able to see any PHP errors in it

Comment: @mohamadmohamad ah, you're on Windows. Then use some folder other than '/tmp', just drop it somewhere that exists and where PHP can write and where you can find the file later.

Comment: @rickdenhaan i receive the same error message if i use the downloads folder or a folder in my root

Comment: OK let's try something else. You're getting the error message all the way at the end of PHPExcel, so I'll assume there aren't any other problems. Can you put the headers back and add an extra `header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");` and see what happens?

Comment: @rickdenhaan use this code header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); without the ob_start() and the ob_end_clean()

Comment: @rickdenhaan when i use this code header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); without the ob_start and ob_en_clean i only receive the second message that i put above

Comment: The official [example](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Examples/01simple-download-xlsx.php) does not use `ob_start()` and `ob_end_clean()`, but it does `exit` immediately after the call to `save()`.

Comment: If the `exit` doesn't work, then I'm out of ideas. Maybe someone else has a clue what's going on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153688/discussion-between-mohamad-mohamad-and-rickdenhaan).

Comment: Tank you it's work now :D

Answer (score 3):

You're doing it the other way around. The only part you need to get into the buffer is `$file->save("php://output");`. If for any reason simply  `exit`ing after saving to output is not enough for you, delete the first `ob_start();` and last line and try this:

```
ob_start();
$file->save("php://output");
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
die($content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing

```
break;
```

in libraries/PHPExcel/Calculation/Functions.php (line 1161)

in public static function TYPE($value = NULL){}

in elseif(is_array($value)) {}

It solved my problem.